# Orbital overlap in E2

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

In order to overlap, orbital lobes must have the same sign of the wavefunction i.e. they must have the right symmetry. In case 2 in the image above, can therefore E2 elimination not occur?

Comment: What is the difference between your case 1 and case 2? I mean, it's clear that you've changed your colouring scheme; but the molecule can't see and doesn't know about your colouring scheme. What about the molecule is different such that you coloured it differently?

Comment: I thought that the molecule knows about the sign of the wavefunction at each orbital lobe and only shaded lobes can overlap with shaded lobes and similarly for unshaded lobes. Are you saying that in general we can flip the sign of the wavefunction of each lobe in any given orbital independently of all other orbitals in the molecule?

Comment: Ok, I think I might have used a bad phrasing. A better analogy is probably the MOs of H2. If you "shade in" both 1s orbitals with the same colour (sign), then the bonding MO is just $\mathrm{1s_A + 1s_B}$, and the antibonding is $\mathrm{1s_a - 1s_B}$. But if you choose to shade them differently, it doesn't change the fact that you have a bonding MO and an antibonding MO. It doesn't even change the final form of the MOs. It only changes the sign that you write: bonding = $\mathrm{1s_a - 1s_B}$, antibonding = $\mathrm{1s_a + 1s_B}$.

Comment: So, are you saying that in general we can flip the sign of the wavefunction of each lobe in any given orbital independently of all other orbitals in the molecule?

Comment: Yes, pretty much, although I'm not beating around the bush just to be annoying. I care more that you understand *why* this is the case, rather than just knowing *that* it is the case.

Comment: Sorry, I can't speculate at all why this is allowed. Could you please explain why?

Comment: That goes back to my second comment: you are mixing orbitals to form other orbitals (in H2 you have 1s & 1s -> σ & σ*, here we have σ & σ* -> π & other bonds). This mixing takes place regardless of the sign of the orbital you ascribe: it's just that if you flip your relative orbital signs, then your mathematical description of the mixing needs a minus sign instead of a plus (or the other way round). Nothing changes from the molecule's point of view.